# Laravel error on php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

Error on php artisan serve

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception ReflectionException with message
>
> ```
> Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in 
> /home/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/
> Container/Container.php:719
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/
> Container.php(719): ReflectionClass->__construct(App\\Console\\Ker...)
> #1 /home/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/
> Container.php(598): 
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build(App\\Console\\Ker...)
> ```

P.S. Class `App\Console\Kernel` does exist

Comment: did you run composer update ? seems like you dont have core files

Comment: yes, I did. The path is wrong. App folder is under resources but its looking for App outside resources

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if laravel supports having the App folder under anything.

At any rate this may or may not work:

Change in `composer.json`:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "resources/app/",
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`

Composer install or update should also work in refreshing the autoloader.

I would highly discourage you placing the app folder under resources. That's not what the resources folder is supposed to contain.

Answer (score 0):

I more hint.
You can remove cache manually and `vandor` folder also, than run `composer install`. This should help.